# How do I quit the game?

Tags: antichamber

Neither escape nor alt+f4 seem to work.  Right now I'm hitting ctrl+alt+delete and manually ending the process when I want to take a break.

Is there a better way to exit the game?

Comment: Good job, UX designer...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hold down escape for a few seconds.

Comment: Should rather be *hammer escape a few times*. Then, at least, people would find out themselves..

Comment: That would be too easy... it's a puzzle game after all. :P

Answer (score 36):

A picture says more than 40 characters:
[image: Hold Esc to quit]

Comment: Do'h​​​​​​​​​​!

Comment: That was exactly 40 characters :P